# Write a program to check the overlapping of one string's suffix with the prefix of another string

Tags: python-3.x, output

```
a = input()
b = input()



def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
    answer = ""
    len1, len2 = len(string1), len(string2)
    for i in range(len1):
        match = ""
        for j in range(len2):
            if (i + j < len1 and string1[i + j] == string2[j]):
                match += string2[j]
            else:
                if (len(match) > len(answer)): answer = match
                match = ""
    if answer == '':
        return 'No overlapping'
    else:
        return answer

print(longestSubstringFinder(a, b))
```

in the above code, not getting the expected outcome for the input
correct
wrong

My output: e
expected output: No overlapping

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- the `else` block should not allow the inner loop to continue: when you have a mismatch, you should not try matches with higher values of `j`, but you should exit that loop and try with the next value for `i`. So there needs to be a `break` in the `else` block
- the condition `len(match) > len(answer)` is not enough to identify a solution. The reason for getting into the `else` block might have been that the characters didn't match, so in that case you should never update `answer`.
- On the other hand, the update of `answer` is not happening now when the inner loop ends normally, i.e. when all compared characters were equal and `i + j < len1` was always true. This case happens when the second input string is a suffix of the first. So you must make the update to `answer` somewhere else, so you also catch this case.

Here is the correction to your code, dealing with these issues:

```
def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
    answer = ""
    len1, len2 = len(string1), len(string2)
    for i in range(len1):
        match = ""
        for j in range(len2):
            if (i + j < len1 and string1[i + j] == string2[j]):
                match += string2[j]
                # Move the assignment to answer here, and add condition that
                #  this was the last character of string1:
                if i + j == len1 - 1 and len(match) > len(answer): answer = match
            else:
                break  # Necessary!
    if answer == '':
        return 'No overlapping'
    else:
        return answer
```

With the use of string slicing, and comparing those slices instead of individual characters, you can make your code shorter and run faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using RegEX, you can do it with lesser lines of code. I'm assuming you're a beginner in Python. If you are, then please learn RegEx and List Comprehension for this type of code.

```
import re
str1, str2 = input(), input()

def longestSubstringFinder(string1, string2):
    
    list_of_subsets = [str1.replace(str1[:i], '') for i in range(len(str1))]

    intersect = [re.search('^'+slc, str2).group() for slc in list_of_subsets if re.search('^'+slc, str2)]

    if len(intersect) == 0:
        return 'No overlapping'
    else:
        return intersect[0]

print(longestSubstringFinder(str1, str2))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = str(input())
b = str(input())
g=len(a)-1
prefix = "No overlapping"
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[(g-i):] == b[:i+1]:
        prefix = b[:i+1]
print(prefix)
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap `input()` in a call to `str()`. That function returns strings automatically.

Comment: Also, this answer would benefit from some explanation.