# Faster way to find overlapping position in 2D Arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suppose there are two 2D matrix, A and B

```
A = [
      [1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9]
    ]
B = [
      [2,3,9],
      [5,6,7],
      [8,9,0]
    ]
```

> A and B are the dimension-wise same. A[i], B[i] are 64 bit integer

We can see that matrix A is overlapping with B from the 2nd column of A. So the position of overlapping is 1 and the length of overlapping is 2;

A naive approach would be as follows:

```
int N = 3; // row
int M = 3; // col
int A[3][3] = {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6},
    {7,8,9}
};
int B[3][3] = {
    {2,3,9},
    {5,6,7},
    {8,9,0}
};
for (int i = 0; i < M;i++) {
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < M-i; j++) {
        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
            if (A[k][i + j] != B[k][j]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (k < N) break;
    }
    if (j == M - i) return i;
}
```

Comment: Which kind of overlappings are possible? only hole columns? Or also hole rows? or even overlapping corners?

Comment: Column-wise. Have to match the full column

Comment: Do the column matches have to be consecutive?  In other words, can column 1 and column 3 of A match B?>

Comment: have to be consecutive. For example:
Start-->0, Check->0,1,2 of A with 0,1,2 of B consecutively. Possiblle overlapping len 3
Start-->1, Check->1,2 of A with 0,1 of B consecutively
overlapping len 2
Start-->2, Check->2 of A with 0 of B consecutively
overlapping len 1

Comment: Related question: [Write a program to check the overlapping of one string's suffix with the prefix of another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66815041/write-a-program-to-check-the-overlapping-of-one-strings-suffix-with-the-prefix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A practical approach is to replace the matrices `A` and `B` with vectors `a` and `b` containing hashes of each column.  Then you check for overlaps in the vectors, and only when you find one do you check to see if the full matrices match with the same overlap.

If your hash function is decent, then the probability of failing a full matrix check will be low.

To find the vector overlaps, you can use a similar strategy, checking hashes of suffixes of `a` against hashes of prefixes of `b`, and only checking the full vectors, and then full matrices, when they match.

To make this an optimization, you need to be able to calculate those prefix and suffix hashes incrementally, so you can get the hash of the next suffix by adding one character to the hash of the previous suffix in constant time.  A common polynomial hash function makes that pretty easy.

For example, if your hash function is:

```
h = 0;
for item in vec:
    h = h*31 + item;
return h;
```

Then you have `hash(concat(x,y))` = `hash(x)*(31^y.length) + hash(y)`